# command + click on vscode doesn't navigate to component file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

Pressing Command + click doesn't navigate to the file of function or component anymore.

vsCode Version: 1.63.2 (Universal)
Node.js: 14.16.0

this is my vsCode settings.json:

```
{
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "prettier.arrowParens": "always",
    "prettier.useTabs": true,
    "[jsonc]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "editor.minimap.maxColumn": 100,
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[json]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
    },
    "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/bash",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": [],
    "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
    "git.suggestSmartCommit": false,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "[php]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "kokororin.vscode-phpfmt"
    }
}
```